# install shield limited edition - backup a file and place it after installation mostly at same place

Tags: installshield-le

I created setup using install shield **limited edition** :(

our requirement is whenever the setup is run, if application already exists, need to uninstall,
before uninstalling, backup a file and place it after installation at same place

how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done only through [custom actions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368066%28VS.85%29.aspx) and it's not supported by InstallShield LE. You can try using a [Visual Studio setup project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Win_App_Setup_Project.aspx) or another setup authoring tool.